# Piano Dynamics problem

Tags: piano

I have a problem with the dynamics of my upright piano. When the sustain pedal is pushed the piano can't play piano or anything close to that, but when I don't press the sustain pedal it's fine. Anyone got a clue?

Edit: Guys the piano was used to play every dynamic range before.

Comment: When the sustain pedal is used, the whole sound of any piano is louder. Other strings vibrate sympathetically, so it will be louder. Press more gently, and/or use the soft pedal.

Answer (score 1):

There will certainly be a richer sound with the sustain pedal down.  That's what letting all the other strings resonate DOES.   It is still possible to play quietly though.   Try physically lifting your hand as your finder depresses the key.  'Take the weight off' the note.

Comment: you can play quietly but its far to difficult that it should be like way far